# TinyMCE : How to assign textbox value on code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce, updatepanel

I have a textbox inside the update panel..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txb1" Class="tinyEditor"  runat="server"1 TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and on Code Behind assigning txb1 value to a hashtable (txbHtbl is a hashtable) ..

```
if (txbHtbl != null && txbHtbl.ContainsKey(selectedId))
{
  txbHtbl[selectedId] = txb1.Text;
  ViewState["txbHtbl"] = txbHtbl;
}
```

for making tinymce working i am added

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    TinyMCEeditor();
});
```

when user change some text and click on some other item of datalist at that time I want to assign changed text or u can say new text of txb1 to txbHtbl[selectedId].

when I am not using update panel then every thing working fine, but then I am using update panel I am not getting latest (changed value) value to textbox.

Please someone help me I am stuck from morning..

Comment: at which point of time do you get the editor content?

Comment: I have a datalist which is inside other update panel and I am binding the datalist I am getting the text from database for a first time, I want to write a fun. by which I code get the latest changed value and store it in viewstate

Comment: per javascript you can get the actual editorcontent using tinymce.get('editor_id').getContent();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added

```
onchange_callback: function(ed) { ed.save(); }
```

to TinyMCE Editor function now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the trigger save method before.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.triggerSave

Comment: I tried to add onchange_callback: function(ed) { ed.save(); } with this its working in IE but in FF its not working...